# React Router removes parent component when path extends

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to have routing withing an existing route, but when I try to apply more routes on top of the existing route, the parent component is no longer rendered.

Here are my parent routes:

```
<Routes>
    <Route exact path = '/Music-Shop' element={<LandingPage />} />
    <Route path = '/Music-Shop/Products' element={<ProductsHome />} />
</Routes>
```

I want to have a Link component lead to /Products/product-category inside the ProductsHome component, and keep it rendering

```
<Link 
  to = '/Music-Shop/Products/Instruments' 
  className = 'sidebarLink'
/>
```

How can I keep extending the /Products path while still rendering the ProductsHome Component?

Comment: you will just want to have another sub Routes inside of the Products Home Component. Or you can have nested routing as shown here: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a /:type to the end of the path you want the parent component to render with

```
<Route path = '/Music-Shop/Products/:type' element={<ProductsHome />} />
```

In the child Component:

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'

export default function ProductDisplay() {

  const { type } = useParams();

  return (
    <>
      {type === 'Instruments' && <Instruments />}
    <>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of methods to achieve this.

### Use nested routes with a parent layout route.

Render `ProductsHome` as a layout route that renders the common UI you want and an `Outlet` component for nested routes to render their content into.

Example:

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const ProductsHome = () => {
  ...

  return (
    <div /* parent UI layout design */>
      ... Products home UI ...

      <Outlet />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Render `ProductsHome` as a layout route and wrap the nested routes you want to render with the common UI.

```
<Routes>
  <Route path='/Music-Shop'>
    <Route index element={<LandingPage />} />
    <Route path='Products' element={<ProductsHome />}>
      <Route path='Instruments' element={<Instruments />} />
      ... other nested routes ...
    </Route>
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

### Use descendent routes.

Render `ProductsHome` on a route with a trailing wildcard matcher `"*"` character so descendent routes can be matched and rendered.

```
<Routes>
  <Route path='/Music-Shop'>
    <Route index element={<LandingPage />} />
    <Route path='Products/*' element={<ProductsHome />} />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

Update `ProductsHome` to render a `Routes` component wrapping the descendent routes.

```
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

const ProductsHome = () => {
  ...

  return (
    <div /* parent UI layout design */>
      ... Products home UI ...

      <Routes>
        <Route path='Instruments' element={<Instruments />} />
        ... other descendent routes ...
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
};
```